# Primefaces 3.4 p:calendar. How to display AM/PM in different Languages (Japanese/Chinese)?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I am trying to use `p:calendar` displaying a datetime (timestamp).

```
PrimeFaces.locales['zh_CN'] = {
  closeText: '关闭',
  prevText: '上个月',
  nextText: '下个月',
  currentText: '今天',
  monthNames: ['一月','二月','三月','四月','五月','六月','七月','八月','九月','十月','十一月','十二月'],
  monthNamesShort: ['一月','二月','三月','四月','五月','六月','七月','八月','九月','十月','十一月','十二月'],
  dayNames: ['星期日','星期一','星期二','星期三','星期四','星期五','星期六'],
  dayNamesShort: ['日','一','二','三','四','五','六'],
  dayNamesMin: ['日','一','二','三','四','五','六'],
  weekHeader: '周',
  firstDay: 1,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: true,
  yearSuffix: '', // 年
  timeOnlyTitle: '仅时间',
  timeText: '时间',
  hourText: '时',
  minuteText: '分',
  secondText: '秒',
  ampm: false,
  month: '月',
  week: '周',
  day: '日',
  allDayText : '全天'
};
```

A script definition

```
<p:calendar locale="zh_CN" pattern="yyyy年MM月dd日 HH点mm分ss秒 aa" value="#{xBean.dateStr}" showOn="button" />
```

But it only displays PM/AM, say pattern = "yyyy年MM月dd日 HH点mm分ss秒 aa".

> 2012年11月21日 21点34分55秒 PM

But I want to make it like this:

> 2012年11月21日 21点34分55秒 下午

How can do this？

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `21点34分55秒` already imply it's PM? I would just use `21:34:55` anyways.